# a question about the bipartition of a graph $2$

Tags: graph-theory

Show that in a bipartite graph with the bipartiton $\{V_1,V_2\}$ the sum of the vertices' grades from $V_1$ is equal with the sum of vertices' grades from $V_2$.

I don't know any way of solving this.

Comment: What can you say about edges in a bipartite graph? So what is the sum of the grades for the vertices in $V_1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All edges link **one** vertex in $V_1$ and one vertex in $V_2$, by definition of **bipartite**.

So number of edges equal sum of vertices' grades from $V_1$ equal sum of vertices' grade from $V_2$

Comment: @AdrianCostea You are very welcome.